# Finding the way to connect 2 data tables with PowerPivot/PowerQuery

Tags: powerquery, powerpivot

THis is my first post. I am new (and self learning) to PowerPivot :)

There are 2 data tables.

Table 1: Data regarding distribution on shop, sku, week level
Table 2: Data regarding actual sales on sku, week level

I can't figure out how to connect tables. Of you have any idea, please let me know! Much appreciated

I can't figure out how to connect tables. Of you have any idea, please let me know! Much appreciated

Please see uploaded image- columns marked with the same color has the same data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58cSy.png)

Answer (score 0):

The way I've learned is to make tables of unique keys values, and always use those, never the actual data tables, in the row or column values of power pivots.

There might be a better way to do this but I use power query to create tables of unique keys, then link these in a one-to-many relationship with the data.

So, if you create queries from each table then you can append the common columns between them with a third query of

```ml
let
  Tables = {Sales, Distribution},
  #"Common Column Names" = List.Intersect(
    List.Transform(
      Tables,
      Table.ColumnNames
    )
  ),
  Combined = Table.Combine(
    List.Transform(
      Tables,
      each Table.SelectColumns(
        _,
        #"Common Column Names"
      )
    )
  )
in
  Combined
```

If you name that query CommonColumns and create a query called fTableColumnDistinct as

```ml
(Table as table, Column as text) as table => Table.Distinct(
  Table.SelectColumns(
    Table,
    {Column}
  )
)
```

then, *per column,* you can get a table of unique values with queries that look something like

```ml
fTableColumnDistinct(
  CommonColumns,
  "column name goes here"
)
```

Load each of these single-column tables into your data model and set up one-to-many relationships with your Sales and Distribution tables.

Now you can create your power pivot. Rows and columns should come from these distinct single-column tables, using only your data tables of Sales and Distribution for the body/data cells of your power pivot.

*(Caveat: code not debugged)*